# JavaScript not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I am having this dynamic dropdown code. Here i want to load the second dropdown options dynamically by changing the first dropdown options. This works fine in all other browsers except IE. I don't know whats the reason as i'm a starter. could any one explain the reason.

HTML CODE:

```
<select name="language" id="language" onchange="SetMedia(this)">
<option>Please select a Language</option>
<option>English</option>
<option>Tamil</option>
<option>Telugu</option>
</select>

<select name="media" onChange="processButtonData(this.value)" id="media" disabled="disabled">
<option>select</option>
</select>
```

JS CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetMedia(objLanguage) {
var objMedia = document.getElementById("media");
objMedia.options.length = 0;
    objMedia.disabled = false;
switch (objLanguage.value) {
case "English":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Please Select a Media",""));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Indian Express","http://www.indianexpress.com"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("The Hindu","http://www.hindu.com"));
    break;
case "Tamil":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Please Select a Media",""));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Dinamalar", "http://www.dinamalar.com"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Dinamani", "http://www.dinamani.com"));
    break;
case "Telugu":
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Please Select a Media",""));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Google","http://www.google.com"));
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("Google2","http://www.google.com"));
    break;
default:
    objMedia.options.add(new Option("select"));
    objMedia.disabled = true;
    break;
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to load before you run your javascript?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working?" What is/isn't happening?

Comment: @jfriend00  I'm trying to fill the second dropdown options based on the option selected from the first one.

Comment: @Evan           onchanging the first dropdown option i want to load the second one but that is not happening. I mean nothing happens.

Comment: It works for me in IE9 in this jsFiddle with your exact HTML and JS: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jY7Tv/.  What version of IE are you seeing the problem in?  And, when you say "doesn't work", what exactly do you observe?  Do you see any errors in the IE debug console?

Comment: IE9 only and i am completely new to this field so i don't know about IE debug console.

Comment: also when i tried to open the jsfiddle link of yours it shows a pop-up saying 'this webpage contains errors.......' and opened a debugger saying "SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
 
select.js, line 168 character 28"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that non-IE browsers (e.g. Chrome) will set the `value` of an `<option>` tag implicitly using it's inner-text, but IE does not do this. You have two options:

1) Set the `<option>` value explicitly

```
<option value="English">English</option>
<option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
<option value="Telugu">Telugu</option>
```

Or,

2) Switch on `text`

```
var language = (objLanguage.options[objLanguage.selectedIndex]).text;
switch (language) {
  // ...
}
```

(Tested in Chrome and IE9.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternative using older method to dynamically add option

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = "";
option.text = "Please Select a Media";
try {
    objMedia.options.add(option, null);
} catch(exception) {
    objMedia.add(option); // Older IE doesn't support the standard
}
```